# How do I set the refresh token for Youtube API in php

Tags: php, youtube-api, token, youtube-data-api

I got a refresh token using OAuth playground, but I am not sure what to do with it. Using the php sample code to upload a video, I added this line of code

```
$client->refreshToken($refreshToken);
```

Is this all I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Few more steps are required once you have the OAuth2 refresh token:

Define the path to credentials file obtain from Google's dev console (also called "client-secret") and set it for $client:

```
$credentialsFilePath = "client_secret_file.json";    
$client->setAuthConfig($credentialsFilePath);
```

Add the required scope [(see here)](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes) which should match the scope defined when you received the refresh token (after first user's consent), this is a scope example for Gmail:

```
$client->addScope('https://mail.google.com/');
```

Set your refresh token (gets a new token and sets it to the $client):

```
$refreshToken = "1/Je...................";
$client->refreshToken($refreshToken);
```

Get your access token (which I like to store in session):

```
$_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
```

Start calling the API:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
    // API calls
}
```

Full code for Gmail requests using OAuth2 with a refresh token:
https://eval.in/776863

Comment: Using the code sample they already set client secret using $client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
and the scope $client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube'); And all the other access token session stuff. So using the pre built code, I only have to ad the $client->refreshToken($refreshToken);?

Comment: Here, I used this https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#upload_a_video

Comment: show me your code (don't paste it here, use eval.in or something else), and i'll try to help

Comment: never mind I just had to put in my client id and secret in oauth playground and then I could use it permanently

Comment: Is correct. If you have `$refreshToken` of your account, only needs `$client->refreshToken($refreshToken);` . You could try later the instruction to validate in a conditional `if ($client->getAccessToken())` (inside it the code for calls to API)